# How to count array elements occurrences in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I have an array in Presto and I'd like to count how many times each element occurs in it. For example, I have

```
[a, a, a, b, b]
```

and I'd like to get something like

```
{a: 3, b: 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

We do not have a direct function for this, but you can combine `UNNEST` with [`histogram`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#histogram):

```
presto> SELECT histogram(x)
     -> FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1111, 1111, 22, 22, 1111]) t(x);
     _col0
----------------
 {22=2, 1111=3}
```

You may want to [file a new issue](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new) for a direct function for this.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    TRANSFORM_VALUES(
        MULTIMAP_FROM_ENTRIES(
            TRANSFORM(ARRAY['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], x -> ROW(x, 1))
        ),
        (k, v) -> ARRAY_SUM(v)
    )
```

Output:
{
"a": 3,
"b": 2
}

Comment: AWS Athena currently doesn't support ARRAY_SUM, I used CARDINALITY instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use REDUCE if there is no support of ARRAY_SUM:

```sql
SELECT
    TRANSFORM_VALUES(
        MULTIMAP_FROM_ENTRIES(
            TRANSFORM(ARRAY['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], x -> ROW(x, 1))
        ),
        (k, v) -> REDUCE(v, 0, (s, x) -> s + x, s -> s)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Presto 0.279`, you now have a direct function for this purpose. You can easily use [array_frequency](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_frequency). The input is your ARRAY, and the output is a MAP, where keys are the element of the given array and values are the frequencies. Fro example, if you run this SQL :

```
SELECT array_frequency(ARRAY[1,4,1,3,5,4,7,3,1])
```

The result will be

```
{
  "1": 3,
  "3": 2,
  "4": 2,
  "5": 1,
  "7": 1
}
```